# Will a makefile work with "truffle compile" so that it only compiles changed files?

Tags: makefile, ethereum, truffle

I am hoping to create a Makefile for truffle to handle my web server as well as my smart contract compilation. Usually, running `truffle compile` will compile all contracts in the `contracts/` folder.

I want to create a makefile that behaves the same as it would when compiling C++ code -- only re-compile if any of those files have changed.

What would this look like in a makefile?

Comment: `truffle compile` should only be compiling contracts that have been modified since the last run. In any case, have you looked into using `solc` directly?

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with truffle, could you explain what the compilation process builds? This sounds like a very straightforward problem, but I don't want to give you bad advice out of ignorance.